# Use LINQ to compare the two lists

Tags: linq

```
public class MyClass
{        
    public int key { get; set; }
    public string fld { get; set; }

    public MyClass(int key, string fld)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.fld = fld;
    }
}
public class MyTest()
{
    MyClass a = new MyClass(1, "apple");
    MyClass b = new MyClass(2, "peach");
    MyClass c = new MyClass(3, "banana");
    MyClass d = new MyClass(2, "orange");
    MyClass e = new MyClass(4, "pear");

    List<MyClass> myList1 = new List<MyClass>();
    myList1.Add(a);
    myList1.Add(b);    
    myList1.Add(e);    

    List<MyClass> myList2 = new List<MyClass>();
    myList2.Add(a);
    myList2.Add(d);
    myList2.Add(c);
}
```

I want to get comparsion of myList1 and myList2 in xml output. 
 In the case, both lists have the same key 1. No need to output this one.
 The key 2 fld is different. So log the 1st list fld value.
 The 1st list doesn't have key 3, in other words, we can think it is removed from the list 1. So log the key 3 and empty fld. The 1st list has key 4, while 2nd list does not. So keep it in the log.
 So the expected output is:

```
<lists> 
  <list>
    <key>2</key>
    <fld>peach</fld>
  </list>
  <list>
    <key>3</key>
    <fld></fld>
  </list>
  <list>
    <key>4</key>
    <fld>pear</fld>
  </list>
<lists>
```

Can anyone shed some lights on how to implement it in LINQ?

Comment: Does the ordering matter? These sound like basically `Dictionary<int, string>` objects, really... are they, or not?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on, the query part of the XML serialization?

Comment: Think about how you would do this outside of Linq. If that idea can be expressed as a series of filters, joins, and projections, then Linq could be useful. Personally, I don't think Linq is necessarily the right tool for this particular task, though someone might suprise me. I have an alternate solution in mind that involves using a dictionary to find matching keys, removing keys with matching values, and then finally adding unmatched keys, and this can be done rather cleanly.

Comment: Jon, no, the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Stanley, yes, you understand me right. I am stuck on query part.

Comment: I missed the case that the key is in the 1st list, but not in the 2nd list. Updated question to include that.

Comment: Note, I believe there's a typo above in the last line where you add `c` to `myList1`. I believe that should be added to `myList2`, to match both your text description and your expected output.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. I corrected the typo to make it as a good reference for other people.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to compare lists A and B with 3 sets of results:

- Items in both lists with the same ID but different "values"
- Items in list A but not in list B
- Items in list B but not in list A

You could do that in three queries:

```
var differentValues = from a in myList1
                      join b in myList2 on a.key = b.key
                      where a.fld != b.fld
                      select a;

var missingKeysFrom1 = myList2.Where(b => !myList1.Any(a => a.key == b.key));

var missingKeysFrom2 = myList1.Where(b => !myList2.Any(a => a.key == b.key));
```

You *could* simplify things a bit by creating an `IEqualityProvider<MyClass>`, but unless you have significant performance issues (or perform these types of queries a lot) it may not be worth it.

Note that your queries would be faster if you used a `Dictionary<int, string>` rather than a list of a custom type.

And Linq is for querying, not creating XML.

Comment: "And Linq is for querying, not creating XML." However, the XML output is just a matter of projection, just as any other.

Answer (score 0):

I noted in the comments above that I might instead elect to use a different approach than Linq due to the multiple considerations of needing to handle unmatched keys and unmatched values, while completely omitting records where everything aligns. I think using a standard loop over a dictionary might express your intent cleaner.

```
var itemDictionary = myList1.ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.fld);
foreach (var item in myList2) 
{
    if (itemDictionary.ContainsKey(item.key)) 
    {
        if (itemDictionary[item.key].Equals(item.fld))
            itemDictionary.Remove(item.key);
    }
    else 
    {
        itemDictionary.Add(item.key, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

This appears to solve your problems as outlined. It loads your first list into the dictionary, then loops against the second list to look for discrepancies, and conditionally adds new keys with empty fields, matching your specification. If we project this dictionary after the fact to XML...

```
var xml = new XElement("lists", 
            (from pair in itemDictionary 
             select new XElement("list", 
                new XElement("key", pair.Key), 
                new XElement("fld", pair.Value))
            ).ToArray()
          );
```

..we get the following output, which also appears to match your specification (when going by your comment that order does not matter).

```
<lists>
  <list>
    <key>3</key>
    <fld></fld>
  </list>
  <list>
    <key>2</key>
    <fld>peach</fld>
  </list>
  <list>
    <key>4</key>
    <fld>pear</fld>
  </list>
</lists>
```